# React Native Expo camera getting zoom to work

Tags: react-native, camera, expo, expo-camera

I am using expo-camera with react native (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/). It states that it takes values between 0 and 1, 0 being default and 1 being maximum zoom. The issue I have is that regardless of what I set this to, expect 0, it always goes to maximum zoom.

No zoom:

```
<CameraContainer
            ref={(camera) => (cameraRef.current = camera)}
            type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
            zoom={0}
        />
```

Max zoom:

```
<CameraContainer
            ref={(camera) => (cameraRef.current = camera)}
            type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
            zoom={1}
        />
```

Also max zoom:

```
<CameraContainer
            ref={(camera) => (cameraRef.current = camera)}
            type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
            zoom={0.2}
        />
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, as I need the zoom to be able to increase and decrease in stages.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd put this out there for anyone having the same issue. After much trail and error I found that you need to add another zero after the decimal place. Doesn't make sense to me but works:

```
<CameraContainer
            ref={(camera) => (cameraRef.current = camera)}
            type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
            zoom={0.02}
        />
```